# Is `AnyObject` special in the language?

Tags: swift

By jumping to the definition of `AnyObject` in Xcode, it seems that `AnyObject` is declared like this:

```
@class_protocol protocol AnyObject {
}
```

However, if I try to declare my own protocol like this, it still doesn't work like `AnyObject`:

```
@class_protocol protocol Foo {
}
@objc class Bar {
}
var x : Foo = Bar() // compile error: Type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'Foo'
var y : AnyObject = Bar() // works
```

I've also tried `@objc @class_protocol protocol Foo` and it also doesn't work.

---

In addition, `AnyObject` has the property that you can call any method on it that was declared anywhere as an `@objc` method. Whereas for any other protocol, you can only call methods on it that the compiler knows the protocol supports:

```
@objc protocol Blah {
    func bogus()
}
@class_protocol protocol Foo {
}
class FooImpl : Foo {
}
var x : Foo = FooImpl()
var y : AnyObject = FooImpl()
x.bogus() // compile error
y.bogus() // works
```

So is `AnyObject` somehow special-cased in the language or something?

Comment: I think what happening is compiler automatically make all class conform to `AnyObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not special in its declaration, it's special in the sense that every class implicitly conforms to `AnyObject`.

The only special thing here is the *implicit* part, so if you type

```
class Foo {}
```

the compiler will actually produce

```
class Foo: AnyObject {}
```

Again, there's is ***nothing*** special about the type system or the `@class_protocol` definition, as you could have achieved the same result by making every class to explicitly conform the `AnyObject` protocol.

Using the compiler to do this automatically, however, was the only sane solution to support legacy Objective-C code.

In order to make your example work, since you don't have the aid of the compiler, you would have to type

```
@class_protocol protocol Foo {}
@objc class Bar: Foo {}
var x : Foo = Bar()
```

---

### Update

Well that wasn't exactly right. `AnyObject` is indeed special when referring to Objective-C compatibility, since you can call any Objective-c method on it and the compiler won't complain.

This is only true for Objective-C methods though.

In your last example, if you take the `@objc` keyword away, it gives a compile-time error on both calls.

```
protocol Blah {
    func bogus()
}
@class_protocol protocol Foo {
}
class FooImpl : Foo {
}
var x : Foo = FooImpl()
var y : AnyObject = FooImpl()
x.bogus() // compile error
y.bogus() // compile error
```

Comment: I've added another part to the question, where you can call any method on `AnyObject` but not with `Foo`. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. According to the official manual:

“AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.”

Comment: but that doesn't mean something else can't represent an instance of any class type too